# Admob for Android Canvas

Tags: android, project, admob, android-canvas

I have a project on going and I am suppose to place Admob ads on canvas in android. Is it possible to place Admob ads on Canvas in Android.

Comment: I am not too familiar with the admob workings, but I suppose you could take the `AdView` and call its `draw()` method with your canvas. Although any way of drawing the ad in a canvas would probably remove most of its functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can place your canvas holding view in a FrameLayout and a admob AdView on top of it like

```
<FrameLayout>
    <CanvasView/>
    <AdView/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Also if your view is sophisticated and you don't want major performance impact you can draw it in a separate window layer. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681436/xml-framelayout-has-lowered-my-opengl-surfaceview-framerate-fps/10294418#10294418).